# Extracting subexpressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, algebra

This is a recurrent topic: replacing subexpressions. See for instance:

```
v = {v1, v2, v3};
expr = v/Norm[v] // Simplify[#, Assumptions -> _ \[Element] Reals] &

(* {v1/Sqrt[v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2], 
    v2/Sqrt[v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2], 
    v3/Sqrt[v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2]} *)
```

Is it possible to go from the developed form of `expr` back to $v/\|v\|$?

Most solutions on this website (such as `CoefficientArrays`) rely on a polynomial form, which is not the case here. Specifying the rule manually (such as `Sqrt[v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2] -> n` does not help, which is not surprising since *Mathematica* handles the expression differently from what it looks like.

This one is a simple example but of course, I would like the solution to work on more intrincated cases, such as:

```
{{-(v1^2/(v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2)^(3/2)) + 1/Sqrt[v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2],
-((v1 v2)/(v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2)^(3/2)), -((v1 v3)/(v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2)^(3/2))}
, {-((v1 v2)/(v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2)^(3/2)), -(v2^2/(v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2)^(3/2)) 
+ 1/Sqrt[v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2], -((v2 v3)/(v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2)^(3/2))}
, {-((v1 v3)/(v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2)^(3/2)), -((v2 v3)/(v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2)^(
   3/2)), -(v3^2/(v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2)^(3/2)) + 1/Sqrt[v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2]}}
```

which is equal to the much simpler
$$ \dfrac{1}{\|v\|}\Big(I_3 - \dfrac{v}{\|v\|}\otimes \dfrac{v}{\|v\|} \Big)$$

Answer (score 1):

We can find the common factor but you can't keep `a {x, y, z}` from multiplying through the vector by `a`. You would have to use `Inactive` or `Hold`/`HoldForm` to keep `Times` from evaluating.  Conceivably, dividing the vector by the common factor `cf` might not automatically simplify, but I couldn't think of such a case.

```
faclist = FactorList /@ expr;
cf = KeyIntersection[AssociationThread @@@ Transpose /@ faclist];
cf = Times @@ Power @@@ KeyValueMap[List]@Merge[cf, Min];
Inactive[Times][
 Times @@@ Apply[Power, faclist, {2}]/cf (*// Factor*),
 cf
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
expr /. a_/Sqrt[v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2] -> a/n

(* {v1/n, v2/n, v3/n}  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: I would like to have fun but it does not work with, say, `expr = 1/Sqrt[v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2]` (why?!) :-)

Comment: Try `1/Sqrt[v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2] /. a_./Sqrt[v1^2 + v2^2 + v3^2] -> a/n`.